# Changing logic - jQuery

Tags: magento-1.9, product, ajax, jquery

I have some buttons to buy and remove products in the cart and I do this through two ajax requests.

Everything is working properly, however for a new product to be added, it is mandatory that the product be removed because the buttons are disabled.

I want to change this structure, so that **every time buy button is clicked**, the product in the cart is **removed and overwritten by the same one that was clicked**.

**Button code:**

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<button style="display: none;" type="button" id="cartaoMensagemRemover<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" title="Remover" class="button btn-cart" onclick="removeCartaotoCart('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span>Remove</span></span></button>
```

**Ajax request code:**

```
function addCartao(product_id){
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product_id).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).show();
                $j.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao') ?>",
                  data: {
                    product_id: product_id
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache : false,
                  beforeSend: function () {
                    //alert("beforeSend");
                  },
                  success: function (retorno) {
                    var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id);

                    $j('#cartao').find(':button').not(button).attr('disabled',true);
                    $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
                    getSubTotal();
                    getGrandTotal();
                  },
                  complete: function () {
                    //alert("complete");
                  },
                  error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
              });
            }

            function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
                $j.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/removeCartao') ?>",
                    data:{
                        itemId: itemId
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        //alert("beforeSend");
                    },
                    success: function(retorno){
                        var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);
                        $j('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',false);
                        $j('.item-custom #trAppend').remove();
                        getSubTotal();
                        getGrandTotal();
                        //alert("Sucess removeCartao");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        //alert("complete removeCartaotoCart");
                    },
                    error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the logical change to be possible, a variable was created to receive the product id so that it is in the cart and the buy button is clicked, to be withdrawn.

**Ajax request code updated:**

```
var productSelected = "";
            function addCartao(product_id){
                alert(product_id);
                if( productSelected != "" ){
                    removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);  // Remove the item in cart, if there is one.
                  }
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product_id).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).show();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).css({'background-color': '#000000'});
                $j.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao') ?>",
                  data: {
                    product_id: product_id
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache : false,
                  beforeSend: function () {

                  },
                  success: function (retorno) {
                    var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id);
                    productSelected = product_id;  
                    alert(productSelected);

                    $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend"<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
                    getSubTotal();
                    getGrandTotal();
                  },
                  complete: function () {

                  },
                  error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
              });
            }

            function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
                productSelected = ""; 
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
                $j.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/removeCartao') ?>",
                    data:{
                        itemId: itemId
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){

                    },
                    success: function(retorno){
                        var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);                            
                        $j('.item-custom #trAppend').remove();
                        getSubTotal();
                        getGrandTotal();
                        alert("Sucess removeCartao");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        alert("complete removeCartaotoCart");
                    },
                    error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
                });
            }
```